# IntelliJ Apache Camel Components/Routes Autocomplete?

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, autocomplete, apache-camel

I am using the latest IntelliJ and was wondering whether there is a good Apache Camel plug-in for auto-complete. There is plug-in, but it really does not give you much. It does not know even basic constructs like 'loop'. There is also JBoss Forge, but when trying the install its Camel extension, it throws exception inside IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

What the *** are you talking about. The plugin knows a lot about every single Camel component and all their configurations.

For the Camel DSL its just plain Java code so IDEA have assistance for that. And if you code in XML DSL then IDEA have assistance for the XSD schema that define the XML DSL.

The IDEA plugin is here: https://github.com/davsclaus/camel-idea-plugin

Comment: First, thanks for your response. 
I am using Java DSL. I am new to Camel and not like you. So, bear with me please :)

I have tried to use CTRL+Space to get a 'loop' and some other simple constructs, but it did not seem to work.
After this message, I have restarted the IntelliJ and now these work. Thank you. 

It is an awesome plugin thanks to you, but it would be great to add a youtube link to the github README to demo how to use it!

One unrelated newbie question, since, I have got your attention. What does transform() without input do? like in transform().simple(....)?

Comment: There is a little bit of javadoc documentation on these methods you can view from IDEA. Transform ( xxx ) and transform . xxx are the same. In the former you provide the expression how to transform as a parameter, and in the latter you provide the expression as a method call (fluent style)

Comment: Oh, it does make sense, now. So, transform() needs to be followed by a method, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java DSL then you don't need any plugin, IDE auto-completion is enough. Xml-DSL has some benefits (e,g. to avoid some builder pattern shortcomings) and IDE auto-completion with XSD schema works well too.

I would suggest Java DSL which has lots benefits compares to XML-DSL.

Comment: Less savvy developers may find XML DSL easier / better. And it dont need to recompile code if you do some changes. However from Camel runtime point of view, they are both equally good, they become the same model that is executed/running at runtime.

Comment: Yes, true, but, IDEA's auto-complete does not help to find out the syntax of a component's route. For example: .to("cql://localhost/spark_dc_only?cql=..."). Here, the component name, of course, you need to know, but once you have "cql:", for the rest, an IDEA's auto-complete could be helpful. The plugin developed by Claus does this!

In Camel we have got often the case to fill in some strings with certain syntax or names, IntelliJ help by itself is not great in these cases. But, for HTML, CSS, or JavaScript, IntelliJ's auto-complete for strings works very well.

Comment: Oh I see your point. One reason why I suggested Java DSL is because the DSL would have to pass compile time, instead of delaying the compile time exception/errors to runtime, which happens in Xml DSL